# Why is my sequence is always 1?

Tags: ping

On my Ubuntu server 12. 04 an usual ping response or result is

```
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
```

For some reason I am not sure of, the response has changed to this

```
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The sequence number **is always 1**, no matter how long I leave it to run, unable to connect to any network.

And it produces result like this more than usual, I install a centos 05 server on a virtual box on this server and the centos can recieve and send signal through the ethernet port, but the Linux server can't.

Comment: What is your `ifconfig` output? Is there an IP address assigned to the ethernet interface?

Comment: yes there is an ip address and d settings looks ok

Answer (score 2):

To allow ICMP ping incoming in your firewall :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

If your OUTPUT policy is set to accept, your server will answer. You can check it with :

```
iptables -L | grep OUTPUT
```

If not, add this rule (not sure of this one, I never did because I globally allow OUTPUT by default - not good to lock ourselves too much :]):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

Anyway, could be good to check your iptables rules about icmp, nay all of them (remove grep for that) :

```
iptables-save | grep icmp
iptables -L | grep icmp
```

Comment: i found the problem. i was setting up an email server so it required i install shorewall. 

after running the second code u suggested i recieve a response 
`LOG level into prefix "Shorewall:OUTPUT:REJECT:"`

Comment: That is not what he is asking: he wants to know why icmp shows 1 >:D